# Why NgModelController properties/methods starts with $

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If you follow this doc http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController , Why the properties/methods starting with $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the convension to differentiate angular's built-in services from user-created data/methods/services.